# convert string to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large text file around 450 mb. I have read it and out come is as string.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import re    
def readInChunks(fileObj, chunkSize=2048):

    while True:
        data = fileObj.read(chunkSize)
        if not data:
            break
        yield data
result=[]
f = open("textfile.txt")
for chunk in readInChunks(f):
    result.append(chunk)
f.close()
```

Result I got is a big string file, let say it result.
And result[0] is given below

```
Alin Deutsch, Mary F. Fernandez, 1998
Alin Deutsch, Daniela Florescu, 1998
Alin Deutsch, Alon Y. Levy, 1998
```

Now I want this string to converted to dataframe in following way

```
      c1                c2                    c3
r1   Alin Deutsch      Mary F. Fernandez     1998
r2   Alin Deutsch      Daniela Florescu      1998
```

Comment: have you tried pandas read_csv() method to read the whole dataset?

Comment: yes, but it consume the ram and system goes to "not responding" sate

Comment: with the chunksize option enabled? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-chunking

Comment: also see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-to-read-a-6-gb-csv-file-with-pandas

Comment: Thanks all of you. I have tried your suggestion. But I get an error.
Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 118, saw 3.
Which lead me to use of **read_fwf**. But problem is that Its not splitting the data into columns, though I am using delimiter.

Comment: You may also want to try setting the option in pandas read_csv(engine : ‘python’). This is more feature complete so may help the tokenizing error